# How to save last state when reload url in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

1.Webview has a `goback` method , it can save web state when click back.

2.My layout is a Linearlayout and it has a webview on top of two button.

3. Every button match a url. Also I add `webView.goBack()` in `onKeyDown` method
4. The first url has a form, the second doesn't have a form

I wrote some info at form in first url, after I click the second button
then ,I click the first button,but the url is reload.but if when I click back
the form info is save. 
I want to save those form info like when I click back button，it can save last form info

I want to save form info in last time, how to do that?

my code is here

```
 private void checkone(String url) {

    if (!Netutils.isNetworkAvalible(MyApplication.mcontext)) {
        fl.removeAllViews();
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.removeAllViews();
        fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fl.addView(mErrorView);

    } else {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fl.removeAllViews();
            }
        },1000);






            Map extraHeaders = new HashMap();
            extraHeaders.put("Referer", "www.emiaoqian.com");
            webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);


            settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setSaveFormData(true);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            settings.setAppCachePath(MyApplication.mcontext.getCacheDir().getPath());

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChomeClient(this) {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {


                    currentProgress = pg1.getProgress();
                    if (newProgress >= 100 && !isAnimStart) {

                        isAnimStart = true;
                        pg1.setProgress(newProgress);

                        startDismissAnimation(pg1.getProgress());
                    } else {

                        startProgressAnimation(newProgress);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                    super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);

                    if (title.contains("404")) {
                        showErrorPage();
                    }
                }
            });


            settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


            String ua = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua.replace("Android", "emiaoqian"));




            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    pg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pg1.setAlpha(1.0f);



                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }



                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {



                    if (url.startsWith("weixin://wap/pay?")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        //startActivityForResult(intent,233);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

                }



                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                    } else {
                        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
                    }


                    if (!(url.equals(Constants.LOGIN)) && !(url.equals(Constants.LOGINOUT))) {
                        if (homeTb != null && supportActionBar != null) {
                            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                            supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
                            homeTb.setTitle("");
                        }
                        radiogroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        nouserl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else if (url.equals(Constants.LOGIN) || url.equals(Constants.LOGINOUT)) {
                        inittoolbar2();
                        radiogroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        nouserl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }


                    if (url.startsWith("https://wx.tenpay.com")) {
                        String newurl = url.substring(url.length() - 12, url.length());
                        LogUtil.e("--", newurl);



                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    showErrorPage();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    showErrorPage();
                }


            });

            fixDirPath();
            // webParentView = (LinearLayout) webView.getParent(); 
        }


}
```

Comment: You have already asked that question. Please answer on the questions there before creating a new one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290821/how-to-save-forms-info-last-time-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can set :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
```

Also to Save in Specify the app cache path :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(mContext.getCacheDir().getPath());
```

And tell me the result.

Comment: no effect,i think code have some question，my code at answer